# Coldfusion Inserting Structure data into DB

Tags: coldfusion

I am having a little stuck in finding a method to correct insert a structure data into my database in CF8.

I have a structure as such

```
struct
COMMENTS    undefined
DESC    1
```

As you can see the comments is showing a value of undefined and I am trying to now insert the data into my database. My db will accept NULL values so I tried the following
on the insert parameter

```
 INSERT INTO AUDIT 
            (
                COMMENTS,
                DESC) 
 VAULES (

        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#object.COMMENTS#" null="#NOT len(trim(object.COMMENTS))#">,
    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#object.DESC#" null="#NOT len(trim(object.DESC))#">,
 )
```

The error I am getting on CF is

```
Error Occurred While Processing Request
Element COMMENTS is undefined in OBJECT.
```

How do I handle this to insert into the DB ? I am thinking of doing if object is undefined insert it as null but unclear how to do this.

Comment: This is just a typo??? Your struct says "COMMENTS" your code says "COMMENT". Its undefined because you have spelt it wrong.

Comment: It was a typo on the post itself. Corrected

Comment: Your question has been answered.  Your problem was an undefined variable.  When that happens, `<cfdump>` is your troubleshooting friend.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have in the code, this is what I would do:

(caveat: this is in cfscript and untested)

```
var object = structNew();
    object.comments = 'this is a comment';
    object.desc = 1;

var _sql = "
        insert
        into   audit
        ( comments, desc ) values ( :comments, :desc)
    ";

var insertQuery = new Query();
    insertQuery.setdatasource(yourdatasource);
    insertQuery.addParam( name="comments", value = object.comments, cfsqltype="varchar");
    insertQuery.addParam( name="desc" , value = object.desc, cfsqltype="numeric");

var resultQuery = insertQuery.execute(sql = _sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following:

```
INSERT INTO AUDIT 
(
   COMMENTS,
   DESC) 
VALUES (
   <cfif isdefined("object.Comments")>
      <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#object.COMMENTS#">
   <cfelse>
      null
   </cfif>,
   <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#object.DESC#" null="#NOT len(trim(object.DESC))#">
 )
```

and if you'd like to use null in place of an empty string as well:

```
INSERT INTO AUDIT 
(
   COMMENTS,
   DESC) 
VALUES (
   <cfif isdefined("object.Comments") and object.Comments neq "">
      <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#object.COMMENTS#">
   <cfelse>
      null
   </cfif>,
   <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#object.DESC#" null="#NOT len(trim(object.DESC))#">
 )
```